# Glossary Of Terms

Tags: glossary

Throughout my document, I have defined terms with

```
\begin{definition}\label{def.def1}....\end{definition}
```

I would like to also gather all of these terms at the end of the document in a glossary section in alphabetical order, referencing and linking to the page in which the term was originally defined.

My question is if 1) there is an easy way to do so (without having to go back through my document and pluck out all the definitions I already defined) and 2) If I can copy any examples specific to the definition and the definition itself to the glossary.

For example, I have something like the below somewhere random in my document:

```
\begin{definition}\label{def.chicken}
 \textbf{Chicken:} A bird that may or may not fly.
\end{definition}

\begin{ex}
The east Mexican chicken weighs upwards of 200 lbs!
\end{ex}
```

And would like both the definition and the example corresponding to the definition moved to a section at the end of the document.

Comment: How is `definition` defined? Since you're not capturing an argument but simply hard coding the thing begin defined, it's not really possible to automate creating the glossary without adding glossary commands to each definition.

Comment: To gather terms, then list them referencing and linking to the page in which the term was originally defined, I'm afraid you have to go back though all the document in order to index the terms. Check [makeindex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) documentation. But if you are making a glossaries of terms, it's [a different beat and package](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries)… Points 1 and 2 are very different in my understanding.

Comment: That the example is outside the definition's environment makes this harder, too. If there is always exactly one example directly after its definition, you might possibly script something, but if there's no pattern, you have to consider each case. There are straighforward ways to extract all `definition` environments outside LaTeX, especially if you are consistent in the way you format your code e.g. `\begin{definition}` always follows a new line and `\end{definition}` always precedes one. But that wouldn't make you a glossary.

Comment: @gildux I don't see it makes much difference to whether this can be automated or not.

Comment: @cfr I was only pointing out that the ability to "gather terms" in any "glossary section" can be as simple as calling `\printglossaries` if the poster agree to use a more adapted formatting. The conversion can be done with a script (awk or other) to convert `\begin{definition}\label{ref}\textbf{naming:} description.\end{definition}` into `\newglossaryentry{ref}{name=naming,description={definition}}` (can include example of course.) I was focused on automating the glossary, but we both agree that automating conversion/rewriting should be done by scripting.

Comment: @gildux Then I'm afraid I didn't understand your earlier comment. What did you mean by `Points 1 and 2 are very different in my understanding.`? I thought you meant the answers to questions 1 and 2 would be very different for an index versus a glossary, but I think you meant something else.

Comment: @cfr I've suggested an simple make index because of the following part: "referencing and linking to the page in which the term was originally defined". In that case, the script would be to convert `\begin{definition}\label{def.key}\textbf{naming:} description.\end{definition}` into for example `\begin{definition}\label{def.key}\index{key}\textbf{naming:} description.\end{definition}` then issue `\printindex` in the section where to print the list of references. It's a different workflow and result/output and I'm still not sure to understand which way the question wants to go.